# How does OFX defines account to be available at block?

Tags: ruby

The code in the OFX module bind an `account` variable in a way that I just can't understand from where it came from!

How does this work? I expected to receive a undefined variable or something but it *DOES* work!

```
require "ofx"

OFX("file.ofx") do
   p account
   p account.balance
   p account.transactions
end
```

From where this `account`comes from, and how to use this technique!?

https://github.com/annacruz/ofx

Answer (score 0):

This is called a *message send* (other languages call it a *method call*). Message sends are a fundamental feature of Ruby. In Ruby, unlike other languages (e.g. Python), you don't need to specify the receiver of the message send explicitly, the receiver will implicitly be `self` if it is not explicitly specified.

So, your code is essentially (somewhat) equivalent to

```
self.OFX("file.ofx") do
   self.p(self.account())
   self.p(self.account().balance())
   self.p(self.account().transactions())
end
```

Note: it is not 100% equivalent because of the rules for `private` methods. `private` methods can only be invoked as result of a message send with an *implicit* receiver, so even though `p` and `self.p` are sending the same message to the same receiver, only the first one works because `p` is `private` and can only be called without an explicit receiver.

Comment: By the way: `OFX` is exactly the same thing, but somehow, it doesn't seem to bother you.

Comment: I was aware of send on ruby. My problem is with account being  in scope with inside the block without being explicitly declared anywhere.

Comment: Again, I am trying to understand why you are singling out `account` here. Why do you think `account` is strange, but `OFX` and `p` aren't? All three of them are method calls, all three of them are not explicitly declared anywhere. Why do you think `account` is special?

Comment: Ofx came from require. The account is only valid inside the block. It happens that the library uses instance_eval which is responsible for that black magic.